# calculating the Fibonacci sequence every k-step

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

So given the Fibonacci sequence
$$F_0 = 0 $$
$$F_1 = 1 $$
$$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}, n \geq 2$$

I randomly come across some comment that show me you can calculate it jumping 2,4,8 or 16-step by starting with the appropriate term in the sequence, as follow:

$$F_{2n}  = 3F_{2(n-1)} - F_{2(n-2)}, n \geq 2$$
$$F_{4n}  = 7F_{4(n-1)} - F_{4(n-2)}, n \geq 2$$
$$F_{8n}  = 47F_{8(n-1)} - F_{8(n-2)}, n \geq 2$$
$$F_{16n}  = (47^2-2)F_{16(n-1)} - F_{16(n-2)}, n \geq 2$$

I test it experimentally and it seem to hold, but I can't figure it out how to get those coefficients let alone get to that formula.

Is that some nice thing with powers or two or it can be generalize to any number you desire?

$$F_{kn} = M_kF_{k(n-1)} - F_{k(n-2)}$$
what is formula for this $M_k$, if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is
$$F_{kn} = (\alpha^k+\beta^k)F_{k(n-1)} - (-1)^k F_{k(n-2)}$$where $\alpha=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$, $\beta=(1-\sqrt 5)/2$.

You can verify it by Binet formula.

Comment: $\alpha^k+\beta^k$ is the $k$th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)

Comment: @lhf that is even better. Speaking of that, I suppose there is also a similar formula for those, given their many similarities