# calculating a second order recurrence relation every k-steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics

so given a general second order recurrence relation

$$S_0 = A$$
$$S_1 = B$$
$$S_n = PS_{n-1} - QS_{n-2}, n \geq 2$$

I want to find an expression for $S_{kn}$ in term of $S_{k(n-1)}$ and $S_{k(n-2)}$ something like

$$S_{kn} = X_kS_{k(n-1)} - Y_kS_{k(n-2)}$$

I suspect it might be more like

$$S_{kn} = M_kPS_{k(n-1)} + (-1)^kQS_{k(n-2)}$$

because that is what work for the Fibonacci sequence ($F_n$, A=0,B=1,P=1,Q=-1), as show in previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476063/calculating-the-fibonacci-sequence-every-k-step), and I later could found the one for the Lucas numbers ($L_n$, A=2,B=1,P=1,Q=-1) which are

$$F_{kn} = L_kF_{k(n-1)} - (-1)^kF_{k(n-2)}$$
$$L_{kn} = L_kL_{k(n-1)} - (-1)^kL_{k(n-2)}$$

So I calculate the direct formulas

$$S_n = \frac{(B-A\beta)\alpha^n + (A\alpha-B)\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}$$

or if $P^2-4Q=0$

$$S_n = \frac{P^{n-1}}{2^n}(PA + n(2B-PA))$$

where $\alpha = \frac{P+\sqrt{P^2-4Q}}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{P-\sqrt{P^2-4Q}}{2}$

and try to calculate this $M_k$, and also assumed that it would be some linear combination of $\alpha^k$ and $\beta^k$ after all so is $L_k$, so I started with $M_k=X\alpha^k + Y\beta^k$ but I guess I mess up somewhere because the term start to banish when it shouldn't or at least I hope so...

So my question is possible to find some expression for $S_{kn}$? or that is something especial for Fibonacci and Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all sequences (with values in $\mathbb{C})$ satisfying the recursion relation $S_n = PS_{n-1}-QS_{n-2}$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space $E$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

If $Q \ne 0$ and if the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial $\chi := X^2-PX+Q$ is not $0$ then the two sequences $(r_i^n)_{n \ge 0}$, where $r_1 \ne r_2$ are the roots of $\chi$, form a basis of this vector space. These two roots are different from $0$.

Now, fix an integer $k \ge 2$ look at the image of $E$ by the linear map $L$, which transforms $(S_n)_{n \ge 0}$ into $(S_{kq})_{q \ge 0}$ (you can also transform $(S_n)_{n \ge 0}$ into $(S_{kq+1})_{q \ge 0}$,  or $(S_{kq+2})_{q \ge 0}$,\ldots, $(S_{kq+q-1})_{q \ge 0}$ and you get the same range). The vector space $L(E)$ is generated by the two sequences $(r_i^{kn})_{n \ge 0}$.

Since $r_1+r_2=P$ and $r_1r_2=Q$, you have $r_1^kr_2^k=Q^k$ and you can compute by recursion $P_k := r_1^k + r_2^k$ (the sequence $(P_n)_{n \ge 0}$ belongs to $E$). Thus
$$(X-r_1^k)(X-r_2^k) = X^2-P_kX+Q^k.$$
The sequence $(r_i^{kq})_{q \ge 0}$ trivially satisfy the linear recursion $T_{q+2}-P_kT_{q+1}+Q^kT_q = 0$.

Hence, for every sequence $(S_n)_{n \ge 0}$ in $E$, the sequences  $(S_{kq})_{q \ge 0}$, $(S_{kq+1})_{q \ge 0}$,... $(S_{kq+k-1})_{q \ge 0}$ satisfy this recursion relation. As a result, for every $n \ge 0$, $S_{n+2k}-P_kS_{n+k}+Q^kS_n = 0$. To see this, set $n=qk+r$ with $q$ integer and $r \in [0,k-1]$.

Comment: is not clear to me how I could get from that to $(S_{kn})_{n \ge 0}$ for some arbitrary k

Comment: @Copperfield. I just have written that for any $k \ge 2$.

Comment: cool, thanks. So, after some calculations I can calculate this $P_k$ serie with the original by setting the initial cases A=2 and B=P in order for its direct formula to have that form, and that is why I get the Lucas number in the Fibonacci one :o